# Polymorphism using template and concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I have this code where `Derived` is a subclass of `Base` and I need to have a different version of the `func` method assuming that `proc` method is common and have a lot of statements.

Does concept and template programming allow such requirement?

The requirement is : having two distinct classes having the same code but each one have his own (specific) func method.

Could I achieve this without inheritance?
Hereunder is the code.

```cpp
// templateInheritance.cpp

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base{
public:
    void func(){                    // (1)
        std::cout << "Base::func\n";
    }

    void proc()
    {
        // huge stuff goes here
        func();
        // huge stuff goes here
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T>{
public:
    void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Derived::func\n";
    }
};

int main(){

    std::cout << '\n';

    Derived<int> derived;
    derived.proc();
    Base<int> base;
    base.proc();            

    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

The expected output:

```
Derived::func
Base::func
```

Comment: You can override a **virtual** function. Templates and concepts are unrelated to this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, could I achieve this even without inherenting from the base class ?

Comment: Achieve what exactly?

Comment: "I need to override the func method" --- no, overriding means one very specific thing and it always involves inheritance and virtual functions. Perhaps you want something other than overriding? Then describe your requirements.

Comment: I updated the question. The requirement is : having two distinct classes having the same code but each one have his own (specific) func method.

Comment: Inject [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) into base class instead of inheritance and  defining `void func()` in general. Then bind a callback you need into constructor. Concept is different thing needed to limit the template types with some restrictions e.g. better version of [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: *"The requirement is : having two distinct classes having the same code but each one have his own (specific) func method...."* **Then you need templates but not polymorphism** You can write a class template and then specialize it for one of the class. Also you should describe the question more, as it is not clear even now what exactly you want. Templates may not be needed here. Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also, **what is the expected output?** Add some more examples into the question.

Comment: @user12002570, I added the expected output to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is, that you want to have compile time polymorphism. That is really simple to implement and one common pattern is [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp)

For simplicity I split your `Base` in a real base and a second Base which can then be used for creating instances while the first is really only the common base.

There is no need for `concepts` nor any meta template programming.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename MASTER>
class Base{
public:
    void proc()
    {    
        // huge stuff goes here
        static_cast<MASTER*>(this)->func();
        // huge stuff goes here
    }    
};

template <typename T>
class Base2: public Base< T, Base2<T>>
{
    public:
    void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Base::func\n";
    }    

};

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T, Derived<T>>{
public:
    void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Derived::func\n";
    }    
};

int main(){

    std::cout << '\n';

    Derived<int> derived;
    derived.proc();
    Base2<int> base;
    base.proc();     

    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

[see live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zjKEx6GrW)

If you already have a C++23 compliant compiler, you can simplify much more by using `explicit this parameter`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base{
public:
    void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Base::func\n";
    }    
    void proc(this auto& self)
    {    
        // huge stuff goes here
        self.func();
        // huge stuff goes here
    }    
};

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T>{
public:
    void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Derived::func\n";
    }    
};

int main(){

    std::cout << '\n';

    Derived<int> derived;
    derived.proc();
    Base<int> base;
    base.proc();     

    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

[see live with explicit this parameter](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ehr3Poh4)

Or if you want to go with runtime polymorphism, you simply use virtual/override.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Base{
public:
    virtual void func(){                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Base::func\n";
    }    
    void proc()
    {    
        // huge stuff goes here
        func();
        // huge stuff goes here
    }    
};

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T>{
public:
    void func() override {                    // (2)
        std::cout << "Derived::func\n";
    }    
};

int main(){

    std::cout << '\n';

    Derived<int> derived;
    derived.proc();
    Base<int> base;
    base.proc();     

    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

[with runtime polymorphism](https://godbolt.org/z/essfnYndT)

Runtime polymorphism takes another indirection by calling the function via a pointer. This takes a minimal amount of additional time. And, that is more important: A virtual function can never be a templated one. So if your design needs templated methods, you have to go with `CRTP` or `explicit this` and can add runtime polymorphism on top by e.g. using `std::variant` & `std::visit`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Template Method Pattern. Note that its name is somewhat unfortunate, the "template" in the name does not refer to c++ templates, but to the more general meaning of the word.

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void func(){
        std::cout << "Base::func\n";
    }

    void proc()
    {
        // huge stuff goes here
        func();
        // huge stuff goes here
    }
};
```

Derived classes override the virtual method `func()`. `proc` itself is not virtual, but calls the virtual `func` which contains the customized code specific to derived classes:

```
struct Derived1 : Base {
    void func() override { std::cout << "derived1\n"; }
};
struct Derived2 : Base {
    void func() override { std::cout << "derived2\n"; }
};

int main() {
   Derived1 d1;
   d1.proc();  // calls Derived1::func()
   Derived2 d2;
   d2.proc();  // calls Derived2::func()
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vb6eavnh4)

I think it is worthwile to compare this to CRTP as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78243117/4117728). Here, `Derived1` and `Derived2` do share a common base class, thats not the case with (classical, pre C++23) CRTP. Here the method have to be virtual, which incurs a small cost.